# Send email from PHP using SSL and what configuration is necessary at th the reciever end in outlook

Tags: php, ssl, outlook, exchange-server

I have been asked to develop a form in PHP which captures data from customers on a website and emails it to 1 of 9 stores depending on the nearest store to the customers location. The client has enquired about security of the customers data as it is transfered over the internet between the website and the PC's in the store. The data isn't especially sensitve, it will contain customers, names, addresses and telephone numbers but no financial details. Is it possible to send this data from the website to the store pc's as an email over ssl? What php libraries or configuration is necessary for this with PHP? Also what setup is necessary on the store end, the instore PC's recieving the data run outlook 2003 and work off an exchange server.

Any insight you can give me on how to achieve a secure way of emailing this data across would be greatly recieved or equally tell me if you think it is overkill and it would be fine just using the standard PHP mail function?

Comment: ssl is a great option but it adds only a small level of security, the message will be encrypted between the SMTP relay points, but at each point its plain text, so if you are an system administrator at any point between sender  and sender the email is readable. considering the content of your mail i wouldn't bother to much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class.phpmailer.php to send mails from existing user over SSL

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "user@mail.com";
$mail->Password = "**********";
$mail->Port = "465";
```

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: assuming the mail server supports ssl